# Simple proof that $x^*x$ is positive in a commutative $C^*$-Algebra

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-algebras

Is there any simple proof (one that does not use continuous functional calculus) for the statement that $\sigma(x^*x)  \subseteq [0,\infty)$ for any $x \in \mathcal{A}$ where $\mathcal{A}$ is a commutative $C^*$-Algebra?

Answer (score 1):

Alright, I should have spend more time before asking. Yes there is such a proof: We have $\sigma(y) = \{\phi(y) \mid \phi \in \mathcal{A}'\}$ where $\mathcal{A}'$ is the set of all multiplicative linear functions $\mathcal{A} \to \mathbb{C}$. Such functions are automatically continuous and *-preserving. But then $\phi(x^*x) = |\phi(x)|^2 \geq 0$.

Comment: Whyis $\phi$ $\ast$-preserving? I think it doesn't need to be so. Not all Abelian Banach algebras satisfy that their Gelfand transform commute with the conjugation operator.  It is relatively easy to give counterexamples. For instance $\ell^1({\mathbf Z})$ with convolution and entrywise conjugation fails that property.

Comment: @AdriánGonzález-Pérez Since every element $x \in \mathcal{A}$ is writable as $x = r+is$ where $r,s$ are self-adjoint, it is suffcient to show that for every self adjoint element $s \in \mathcal{A}$ we have $\phi(s) \in \mathbb{R}$. But if $\phi(s) \not \in \mathbb{R}$ we can assume by scaling that $\phi(s) = i$. If we have for $N > 0$ that $(1+N)^2 = ||i(1+N)||^2 = ||\phi(s+Nie)||^2 \leq ||s+Nie||^2 = ||(s+Nie)^*(s+Nie)|| = ||s^2+N^2e|| \leq ||s^2|| + N^2$, and hence $1+2N \leq ||s^2||$. But since $N > 0$ was arbitrary, we get a contradiction.

Comment: @AdriánGonzález-Pérez I now see where the confusion comes from: I forgot to mention that I am dealing with a $C^*$-Algebra with unity. In my question I forgot to mention that completely. Thank you for your comment!